# How long will I be a "new member" for?

Tags: support, new-users

How long will I be a "new member" for?

Comment: What are you talking about? Where are you labelled "New member"?

Comment: I don't think I am anymore, but I'm not sure.

When you are a "new member", you can only post one question every 20 minutes. Do you have to do the "Are you a robot?" thing, too?

Comment: These functions will be unlocked according to your reputation count. Check out http://stackoverflow.com/faq But yes, I do get the robot check, too, every day. Arggh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, some limiting measures (like posting questions more often than 20 minutes, adding links...) will go away with the amount of reputation you accumulate, pretty quickly. These are mainly spam protection mechanisms.

For details, see [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

The robot check, though, doesn't go away - I get it almost daily.

Comment: lol you changed your name again I see.  I wonder what it's going to be next month ;-)